# Track user writing to a directory

Tags: linux, bash, file, permissions

There is a (linux) directory like below:

/a/b/c/d

which is accessible from multiple machines (NFS)

Now, the owner of everything in that directory is dir_owner.

However, someone/ something who/ which can sudo as dir_owner is changing the permissions of directory d to 777 and then writing to that location as a different user. This different user is always the same user, say, unauthorised_user.

I was hoping to track what is causing this. Could someone please help me out on this? Let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Something like [this](https://linux-audit.com/monitoring-linux-file-access-changes-and-modifications/)  maybe? Voting to close the question because not in scope for SO, but I suggest that you ask it again at [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @user1934428 [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) seem more appropriate.  I second the use of auditing, too.

Comment: You can use inotify

Comment: Is the "different user" always the same?  You can put an extended attribute on that directory that removes write permission from that user and see who complains... :-)

Comment: Yes Andrew, its always the same user who writes. (But that different user does not have permissions to change the directory permissions - it is being changed by someone else who can sudo as the original user and then being written by the "different" user). I will add this info in the question. I think being able to track what changes permissions should be helpful. I didn't get a chance to try these solutions, I will take a look at them and get back with what I find.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `stat` command, which is used for viewing file or file system status.

More information and parameters for `stat` on the following webpage.
https://ss64.com/bash/stat.html

Another command is `auditd`, which should be able to be configured writing audit records to the disk, more information at the following webpage,

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/auditd.8.html

Comment: Thanks, however, I think this probably won't help track what changed permissions and what wrote it there (human or script). Please let me know if I am missing something.